# Cannot see cucumber snippets on logs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, cucumber

I've juste start a sping-boot project version 2.1.6 (using starters : spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-test)

And i'm trying to use cucumber for java in version 4.7.1 with following maven dependeces : cucumber-spring, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java8.

When I launch my Acceptance tests, I see when a step is undefined on logs. But no snippets appear

AllAcceptanceTests

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "html:FeaturesReport"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        snippets = CucumberOptions.SnippetType.UNDERSCORE)
public class AllAcceptanceTests {
}
```

My Scenario

```
  Scenario: Creation from initialisation
    Given name "Jean"
    Given gender "Male"
    Given picture "picture.png"
    Given account identifier 1
    When try to create the profile with these parameters
    Then the profile id = 1 , name = "Jean" , gender = "Male" and picture = "picture.png" is saved
```

Junit log

```
  Scenario: Creation from initialisation                                                            # src/test/resources/features/create-profile.feature:9
    Given name "Jean"                                                                                       # ProfileSteps.java:23
    Given gender "Male"                                                                                     # ProfileSteps.java:27
    Given picture "picture.png"                                                                             # ProfileSteps.java:31
    Given account identifier 1                                                                              # null
    When try to create the profile with these parameters                                                    # ProfileSteps.java:37
    Then the profile id = 1 , name = "Jean" , gender = "Male" and picture = "picture.png" is saved # ProfileSteps.java:46

io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedThrowable: The step "existing account in nisfee-account :" is undefined
```

I'm using all spring-boot default configuration. Did i forget something for having somthing like this in my logs :

```
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^today is Sunday$")
public void today_is_Sunday() {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running through JUnit rather then the CLI or IDEA you have to add the `summary` plugin explicitly.

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"summary", "pretty", "html:FeaturesReport"},
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes i'm workin on intellij and the step generator of intellij ignore datatables, this is why i need this feature for working quickly. Previous versions we didn't have to specify this plugin, it is completly new for me ^^